# check multiple directories and output status

Tags: arrays, bash

Hello I am trying run a script that checks for a list of directories. then output the status of each directory into new fields or an array.

Thanks in Advance!

```
#!/bin/sh
    
dir00="/tmp/Apple"
dir01="/tmp/Banana"
dir02="/tmp/Carrot"
dirList=("$dir00" "$dir01"   "$dir02")

dirName00="Apple"
dirName01="Banana"
dirName02="Carrot"
dirNames=("$dirName00" "$dirName01" "$dirName02")

for i in "${dirList[@]}"; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "Directory Not Missing:$i"
        # write to a new arrary (dirStatus) either 0 or 1 
    else
        echo "Directory Missing: $i"
        # write to a new arrary (dirStatus) either 0 or 1 
    fi
done

# then I can do the following:
echo dirName[0] dirStatus[0]
# expected output:
echo Apple 1 # if Apple is missing
```

Comment: By the way: All-caps variable names indicate environment and special variables by convention. To avoid name collisions with those the convention is to use lowercase variable names in bash.

Comment: Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 2):

The test `[ -d path ]` sets the exit status `$?`. Instead of using that status implicitly in an `if` statement you can append it explicitly to an array.
An exit status of `0` means "yes" and everything else (usually `1`) means "no".

Since you didn't specify how exactly you'd like to store the results, here are two alternatives that could be useful:

#### Two Regular Arrays

```
#! /bin/bash
path=(tmp/DIR_0{0..2})
isDir=()
for p in "${path[@]}"; do
  [ -d "$p" ]
  isDir+=($?)
done
declare -p path isDir
```

#### One Associative Array

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A isDir
for p in tmp/DIR_0{0..2}; do
  [ -d "$p" ]
  isDir["$p"]=$?
done
declare -p isDir
```

Comment: I changed up the original example

Comment: @user9980782 After your edit I don't understand what exactly you need help with and why you want to store the `[ -d ]` results in an array. Could it be that you want to know how to find the name of the currently used variable (e.g. `i=/Usersx` => `dir01`)? If so, that would be a totally different question. In that case, please close this question and create a new one.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, yup I agree w/you I am struggling on how to ask what I am looking to achieve. I am going to write it w/o an array and maybe my ask will make more sense.

Thanks again